# How to give setter a 2nd parameter in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parameters, properties, default, setter

I want to know whether we can do such in Delphi:
I have a private procedure:

```
procedure SetMySend(const oValue: TTM_MySend_Profile;
    displayValue: string = '...');
```

I have a public property:

```
property MySend: TTM_MySend_Profile displayLocateID '...'
    read FMySend write SetMySend;
```

Can I give a parameter displayValue here as the 2nd parameter of the setter? I cannot get this compiled.

I cannot figure out the correct way to do it and wonder whether I can do this in Delphi. Thanks for help!

Comment: IMHO, this should be a specific category in SO... something like 'questions' I never think before...@spspli, don't get it wrong, it is only unusual to have a setter with 2 params...

Comment: Why is it beneficial to set two things in one property? Why not set them separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A property setter for a property takes only one parameter, of the same type as the property. There is no syntax that would allow you to write the type of code you are attempting to write. Note that I am ignoring [array properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Array_Properties) which are not pertinent here.

What you need to do is to write a dedicated setter which supplies the extra parameter to your `SetMySend` function.

```
procedure SetMySend(const Value: TTM_MySend_Profile; 
    const displayValue: string); overload;
procedure SetMySend(const Value: TTM_MySend_Profile); overload;
property MySend: TTM_MySend_Profile read FMySend write SetMySend;
```

And then in the implementation you write

```
procedure TMyClass.SetMySend(const Value: TTM_MySend_Profile);
begin
  SetMySend(Value, '...');
end;
```

You could hijack [index specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Index_Specifiers) to effect something similar, but I would not recommend that.